# Error knitting file in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, pandoc

I am getting this error when I attempt to knit any markdown file in RStudio.

> Error in system(paste(shQuote(pandoc_path), "--version"), intern = TRUE) : 
>     'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\PROGRA~1\RStudio\bin\pandoc\pandoc.exe --version'
>   Calls:  ... get_pandoc_version -> with_pandoc_safe_environment -> force -> system
>   Execution halted

pandoc.exe is in the path shown by the error message.

I also have a stand-alone installation of pandoc and have used the following command to point to that version

> Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Pandoc")

Doing that however results in the same error except that the path

> "C:\PROGRA~1\RStudio\bin\pandoc\pandoc.exe" changes to "C:\PROGRA~2\pandoc\pandoc.exe"

I am running Windows 10 and the latest versions of RStudio and R.

Comment: Have you tried running R as admin? Never seen the error but that would be the first thing I'd try when a system() command fails...

Comment: Jon - Brilliant! That did the trick. So grateful for this!

Comment: Happy to hear that! You can upvote my comment if you like (that's how people get their reputation points here) ;)

Comment: @JonGrub No, it's not, you need to post this comment as an answer so we can upvote it and OP can accept it :)